# How to plot timestamp(x-axis) and temperature(y-axis) using D3 while getting data update in real-time from socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph, socket.io

This code bellow which I have got on my research is similar to what I need except that what I need to do is starting my plotting at first

```
  socket.on('new_data', /* do update graph */)
```

I did that but that causes error between my case as my domain is timestamp so now when on the definition of range it comes with an error that **Unexpected number***
The picture that I attached in this question contains my data which comes from socket.on('new_data', ''); which I consoled, now I need to plot a graph using D3 as data comes. Please help[Screenshot of the console of my data from socket.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMzve.png)

Below is the code I say update but for different domain as my case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bost.ocks.org/mike/style.css?20120427">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 8pt;
            line-height: 12pt;
            background: #ffffff;
            color: #555555;
        }

         .axis path, .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #555555;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: orange;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var t = -1,
            n = 40,
            duration = 750,
            data = [];

        var margin = {
            top: 6,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 40
          },
          width = 560 - margin.right,
          height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([t - n + 1, t])
          .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.time.scale()
          .range([height, 0])
          .domain([0, 400]);;

        var line = d3.svg.line()
          .interpolate("basis")
          .x(function(d, i) {
            return x(d.time);
          })
          .y(function(d, i) {
            return y(d.value);
          });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
        var axis = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(x.axis = xAxis); 

        var path = svg.append("g")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
          .append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line");

        function tick() {

          // update the domains
          x.domain([t - n + 2, t]);

          // redraw the line
          svg.select(".line")
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("transform", null);

          // slide the x-axis left
          axis.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .call(x.axis);

          // slide the line left
          path.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t - n) + ")");

          // pop the old data point off the front
          if (data.length > 40) data.shift();

        }
        tick();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may convert the tiemstamp to minits or hours or days either from werverside or client side

Comment: Thanks for your reply LDS, The saddest thing I started learning D3 2 days back now I haven't figured out how I can do that, now this is required tomorrow to be submitted which was given to me as an interview task. Please help me out on how I will do that, I have been searching all around since Friday, helping me out initialize this graph and do the conversions as you have suggested or provide me any sample code I would start working on.

Comment: I have created a fiddle which I am trying to accomplish this, please check it out here and help me fix it up: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fezekilePlaatyi123/0zLt28od/35/) @LDS. My JSON Object is as seen in a variable called data in such fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I was not in online from 4 days .You did not provide the dataset to the d3 object

Comment: @LDS thanks I had solved the problem using Ploty.js, I moved from D3 to ploty